# Is it reasonable for a new PhD student to take a week to read two papers?

Tags: phd, research-process

I have just started my PhD (first semester) in electrical engineering and my adviser is concerned with my progress. My supervisor requires me to present at least one paper every three days. How do I go about handling that? Reading one paper in only three days is a struggle, and most of the time I don't do that well on the presentations, as it is hard to remember the details of the paper.

What is the normal pace of reading research articles when you are new to the field?

Comment: Please mention your department as well. I'm myself a current first year student, but I suppose other people will be better able to provide an answer if you mention your department. Expectations vary across different departments.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's really hard to say without more info. If you're reading cutting-edge papers in a new (to you), highly-technical field when English is not your first language, 2 papers/week seems reasonable. I admit that in most cases, though, 2 papers/week does seem a bit on the slow side. Maybe you need to read more papers less deeply?

Comment: Would reading papers from the latest reputable conferences be considered cutting-edge ?  And yes a lot of peers I talked suggested not to read papers that deeply. What do you exactly then mean to read a paper ?

Comment: "Papers-per-week" seems a useless measure of progress or of effort. Some papers are three pages long; others are over 100 pages long. Some papers are well-written; others are a confused mess. Some papers introduce amazing new ideas; others just slightly modify things you already know. All these differences will affect how many papers you can read in a week.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasBlass that "papers per week" is an odd measurement of progress. I would recommend not reading the article word-by-word in its entirety. If the articles are discussing similar topics, then a lot of the introductions or reviews of literature will be redundant. Focus on the key points (usually found in results/discussion/conclusion/implications) and try to only carefully read the articles in its entirety if it's critical for your own research (for the sake of saving time).

Comment: As you guys are suggesting this is not a good measure of progress then how should I or my professor should gauge ? By the hours spent of literature review ?

Comment: In my first year of my PhD in statistics (I am now in the second) I sent my supervisor a few unsolicited notes about what I had been doing. They of course included references to papers I had read. He was then able to suggest other papers that I should read, but he could also see what progress I was making.

Comment: @JeremyC You method does sound reasonable but my supervisor requires me to present at least one paper every three days apart. How do I go about handling that? It is achievable sometimes but most of the times I don't do that well on the presentations.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more answerable; perhaps it will be re-opened. Note, I removed your secondary question about how to give a good presentation; that's a separate question that would have to be in a separate post (though "how to make a good presentation" is too broad to be answerable).

Comment: In my field of biochemistry, biophysics, and molecular biology, we discuss 2 papers per week in just one of my classes. The depth of knowledge that we (including my instructor) glean from these is relative to our knowledge in the field. Biophysics papers make a lot more sense to my instructor than molecular biology papers, but we discuss everything. My favorite journals and document types are "Methods in Molecular Biology" (tells you exactly how an experiment was performed in reproducible form) and review articles simplify things quite a lot. I also sort articles by citation popularity.

Comment: Also, if you select the text of a PDF article in XODO PDF Reader and Editor, it will audibly read the article for you. I think Google Chrome also has an extension for reading articles, too.